# what is Path and how to find number of possible paths of length $r$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, terminology

The word path is used in different way in different contexts. But I can't related them with each other. Like

> [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mathematics-walks-trails-paths-cycles-and-circuits-in-graph/) **${}^1$Path**: It is a trail in which neither vertices nor edges are repeated i.e. if we traverse a graph such that we do not repeat a vertex and nor we repeat an edge.
>   [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1417664/565609) **Path**: A path in a graph is a subgraph of a given graph that is isomorphic to a path graph.
>   [kenneth rosen discrete mathematics](https://books.google.com.bd/books/about/Discrete_Mathematics_and_Its_Application.html?id=scsMURv-atsC&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=A%20path%20or%20circuit%20is%20called%20simple%20&f=false) **Path**: Let n be a nonnegative integer and G a directed graph. A path of length n from u to v in G is a
>   sequence of edges $e_1,\cdots,e_n$ of G such that $e_1$ is associated with $(x_0,x_1)$, $e_2$ is associated with $(x_1,x_2)$, and so on, with $e_n$ is associated with $(x_{n-1},x_n)$, where $x_0=u$ and $x_n=v$. When there are no multiple edges in the directed graph, this path is denoted by its vertex sequence
>   $x_0,x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n$.  path of length greater than zero that begins and ends at the same vertex is called a circuit or cycle. A path or circuit is called simple if it does not contain the same edge more than once.

**Question $2$**: How many paths of length four are there from $a$ to $d$ in the simple graph $G$ in Figure $8?$[image]
So there are exactly eight paths of length four from a to d according to their solution. But it can't possible without $\color{red}{\text{repeated vertices}}$. Which seem conflicted to the first definition${}^1$. So I really confused which definition should I follow or I have misunderstood something with these defintions. Besides provide me a list something like:

> $(1)$ Walk can be repeated anything
>   $(2)$ Vertex can be repeated Edges not repeated in Trail
> $ \vdots $

Thanks for your time.
Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3392164/minimum-number-of-edges-in-a-cycle-in-directed-and-undirected-graphs/3409965#3409965) and Matthew Daly's comment. In this case, I would say (and many others) that the $ij$th entry $a_{ij}$ of $A^n$ is the number of *walks* of length $a_{ij}$ from $v_i$ to $v_j$, where $A$ is the adjacency matrix (More information in [this stack exchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1890620/finding-path-lengths-by-the-power-of-adjacency-matrix-of-an-undirected-graph).)

In this particular text, it looks like *path* is defined to be as what is otherwise referred to as a walk, and then they use simple to clarify, which is not uncommon.

I'd recommend taking a look at Douglas West's Introduction to Graph Theory if you can, specifically sections $1.1$ and $1.2$. I believe West defines a path graph in section $1.1$ and implicitly uses the "isomorphic to a path graph definition" in section $1.2$.

Comment: Sorry for late response @Hendrix Sir. Yes now it make sense. One question Is it possible for a path that have repeated edges also and Can you suggest me a good book for Graph theory for deep understanding. Because at that time I used kenneth rosen discrete mathematics book which seem not so covering and interesting to read. And Yes I will accept your answer after your response Sir. Thanks again

Comment: @emonhossain In Rosen's text, it seems a path can have a repeated edge. In my linked answer no. It all depends on how you choose your definitions. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27480/what-are-good-books-to-learn-graph-theory) are some good recommendations. Diestel is nice and available for free online. My personal experience was learning from Miklos Bona's A Walk Through Combinatorics, and now I use Douglas West's book (while not always friendly, it is insightful and has a wealth of enlightening exercises, and statements are precise.)

Comment: Ok Thanks for you recommendation @Hendrix Sir